# fb login doesn't ask for credentials for login even after logging out iOS swift 4

Tags: swift, facebook

I am implementing fb login in iOS app, want to login using different fb accounts in same app.

I've installed sdk using cocoapods and not using any third party library. swift 4, Xcode 9,

let manager = LoginManager()

```
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton, didCompleteWith result: LoginManagerLoginResult?, error: Error?) {

    if (AccessToken.current == nil){
    //loginButton.loginBehavior = .browser
    DispatchQueue.main.async(){
  // LoginManager.init(loginBehavior: .web, defaultAudience: .everyone)

        print(LoginBehavior.self)
    self.manager.logIn( permissions: [ .publicProfile, .email ], viewController: self){(result) in
        switch result {
        case .cancelled:
            print("user cancelled login process")
            break
        case .failed(let err):
            print("login failed with error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
            break
        case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
            print(accessToken)
          //get user profile


        }
    }
    }
    print("login")
    } else {
        print("user is already Logged in")
    }
}
func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton) {
    AccessToken.current = nil
    manager.logOut()
}
```

I can login and logout. but it doesn't ask me to enter password next time I try to login. means I can not login using different fb account.

also in AppDelegate file I am getting error implementing fbsdk functions:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

     SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions) 
     return true
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
   return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)

   }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you login into the Facebook application or in mobile browser it keeps an active session until and unless you explicitly logout. When any user tries to log in with Facebook in the third party application then if the user is logged in from the Facebook application or through site in mobile browser then it will not ask the user to log in and that logged in account will be directly used. You have to logout from the Facebook app or mobile browser to login with different account. From the first time from your application if user logs in to the Facebook and enters the Facebook credentials then it will save that session in the mobile browser or Facebook application(if available) so next time it won't ask for the credentials again.

Call below function to logout :

```
FB.logout(function(response) {
  // user is now logged out
});
```

Please refer different cases in the logout scenarios from the below link :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout

Hope this helps you.

Comment: your explanation is perfect regarding my case. Didn't used FB.logout() , still my problem solved. Thanks.

Comment: May I know how did you solved that without 'FB.logout'?

Comment: my application was just having issues with cached data. as you explained.

Comment: Ohh ok. I thought you found out another way except these. Thank you.

Comment: thanks so much for this, it helped me a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

You must have it saved in key chain thats why it is not asking for credentials again. Please try deleting or logging out your account from your native fb app and try again.

Comment: thanks for your kind reply but I am not using keychain

Comment: I mean your device uses keychain. Please try deleting your account from your native fb app and try again.

Comment: well,i've checked my code, it seems to have it saved somewhere, keychain I think so. how to handle it??